# How do I correctly add collisions between a player and wall in JavaScript Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, collision-detection, game-physics

I've made a codepen in order to better explain my situation.
https://codepen.io/kennyfully1988/pen/yLqpBVp

I'm working on a game where the player collects apples. The collision is working correctly when a player touches an apple. (The player will get 1 point and the apple will be erased from the apples array).

What I'm confused about is the following function

```
    checkSolidCollisions(walls) {
        // check to see if player is colliding with walls
        for (let i = 0; i < walls.length; i++) {
            if (
                this.dx <= walls[i].x + walls[i].width &&
                this.dx + this.dw >= walls[i].x &&
                this.dy <= walls[i].y + walls[i].height &&
                this.dy + this.dh >= walls[i].y
            ) {
                console.log(true);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I created this function hoping that this will be a check to see if the player is in collision with a wall (the wall array). However, it doesn't seem to work at all. I'm willing to provide as much information as needed in order to solve this problem. I want you all to know that this is OOP JavaScript.

So, what I tried to do is make the player not be able to pass the wall. However, the player always passes the wall.

[image: the bug where the player always passes the wall]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a long time of testing everything out and rebuilding samples, I noticed what I did wrong. I didn't write the proper logic to see what happens after the player collides with the wall, such as pushing the player back into a safer position after the collision.

// Working code

```js
'use strict';

window.onload = () => {
    const gameBox = document.querySelector('.game-box');
    const ctx = gameBox.getContext('2d');
    const collisionCheckerLabel = document.querySelector(
        '.collision-checker-label',
    );
    let collisionChecker = false;

    const playerImage = new Image();
    playerImage.src =
        'data:image/png;base64,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';

    class Player {
        constructor(config) {
            this._rng = String(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)).padEnd(3, '0'); // random number generator
            this._id = `player_${new Date().getTime()}${this._rng}`; // generated id
            this.image = playerImage;
            this.currentFrame = 1; // helper variable to help with requestAnimationFrame()
            this.totalFps = 60; // helper variable to help with requestAnimationFrame()
            this.totalImageFrames = 4; // the number of frames in the sprite
            this.sx = config?.sx || 0; // source x position
            this.sy = config?.sy || 0; // source y position
            this.sw = config?.sw || 16; // source width
            this.sh = config?.sh || 16; // source height
            this.dx = config?.dx || 0; //destination x position
            this.dy = config?.dy || 0; //destination y position
            this.dw = config?.dw || 16; //destination width
            this.dh = config?.dh || 16; //destination height
            this.animation = config?.animation || 0; // lazy way to play animations

            this.movement = config?.movement || 'idle'; // player movement
            window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (e.key === 'ArrowUp') {
                    this.movement = 'up';
                } else if (e.key === 'ArrowDown') {
                    this.movement = 'down';
                } else if (e.key === 'ArrowLeft') {
                    this.movement = 'left';
                } else if (e.key === 'ArrowRight') {
                    this.movement = 'right';
                } else {
                    this.movement = '';
                }
            });

            window.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                this.movement = 'idle';
            });
        }

        render(ctx) {
            ctx.drawImage(
                this.image,
                Math.floor(
                    this.currentFrame / (this.totalFps / this.totalImageFrames),
                ) * 16,
                this.animation * 16,
                this.sw,
                this.sh,
                this.dx,
                this.dy,
                this.dw,
                this.dh,
            );
        }

        update(ctx) {
            // player animation
            if (this.currentFrame >= this.totalFps - 1) {
                this.currentFrame = 1;
            } else {
                this.currentFrame++;
            }
            // player movement
            if (this.movement === 'up') {
                this.animation = 1;
                if (this.dy <= 0) return;
                this.dy--;
            } else if (this.movement === 'down') {
                this.animation = 0;
                if (this.dy + 16 >= ctx.canvas.height) return;
                this.dy++;
            } else if (this.movement === 'left') {
                this.animation = 2;
                if (this.dx <= 0) return;
                this.dx--;
            } else if (this.movement === 'right') {
                this.animation = 3;
                if (this.dx + 16 >= ctx.canvas.width) return;
                this.dx++;
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    class Rectangle {
        constructor(config) {
            this.color = config?.color || 'black';
            this.x = config?.x || 0;
            this.y = config?.y || 0;
            this.width = config?.width || 16;
            this.height = config?.height || 16;
        }

        render(ctx) {
            ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    }

    const rects = [
        new Rectangle({ color: 'red', x: 32, y: 32 }),
        new Rectangle({ color: 'green', x: 160 - 32, y: 160 - 32 }),
        new Rectangle({ color: 'blue', x: 96, y: 96 }),
    ];

    const player = new Player({ dx: 0, dy: 0 });

    const renderScene = () => {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

        rects.forEach((rect) => {
            rect.render(ctx);
        });

        player.render(ctx);
        player.update(ctx);

        requestAnimationFrame(() => renderScene());

        for (let i = 0; i < rects.length; i++) {
            if (
                //Check x
                player.dx + player.dw > rects[i].x && // right side
                player.dx < rects[i].x + rects[i].width && // left side
                // Check y
                player.dy + player.dh > rects[i].y && // bottom side
                player.dy < rects[i].y + rects[i].height // top side
            ) {
                collisionChecker = true;
                collisionCheckerLabel.innerText = collisionChecker;
                if (player.movement === 'up') {
                    player.dy++;
                } else if (player.movement === 'down') {
                    player.dy--;
                } else if (player.movement === 'left') {
                    player.dx++;
                } else if (player.movement === 'right') {
                    player.dx--;
                }
                return;
            }
            collisionChecker = false;
            collisionCheckerLabel.innerText = collisionChecker;
        }
    };

    renderScene();
};
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: lightgray;
    height: 100vh;
}

.game-box {
    border: 0.5rem solid black;
    height: 90%;
    image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"
        />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="#" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
        <script defer src="app.js"></script>
        <title>Rect Collisions</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Rect Collisions</h1>
        <canvas class="game-box" width="160" height="160"></canvas>
        <p>
            Are the objects colliding? <span class="collision-checker-label">No</span>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Collisions working on walls]

Answer (score 0):

In your example the

```
this.dx + this.dw >= walls[i].x
```

criteria proved to be problematic, because the right edge of the character is not to the right of the wall. A good way to check algorithmically is as follows:

```
    checkSolidCollisions(walls) {
        // check to see if player is colliding with walls
        for (let i = 0; i < walls.length; i++) {
            if (
                !((this.dx + this.dw < walls[i].x) || (walls[i].x + walls[i].width < this.dx)) &&
                !((this.dy + this.dh < walls[i].y) || (walls[i].y + walls[i].height < this.dy))
            ) {
                console.log(true);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

To summarize:

- it is not true that

  - rectangle1 is to the left of rectangle2
  - or rectangle2 is to the left of rectangle1
- and it is not true that

  - rectangle1 is above rectangle2
  - or rectangle2 is above rectangle1

Comment: I tested this code and... first of all, I really appreciate your answer. I feel like it may have been either my confusing code or the way that I've written my question, but after testing your code, it was doing the opposite of what I think I was asking. However, it truly was one step in the right direction, so thank you.

Comment: @kennyfully88 can you provide sample input values for which the above is doing the opposite?